# How to take the average between two values in a column and place this value in between them in Excel?

Tags: excel, average

I have data in column A that goes from 360-800 in steps of 2 (360, 362, 364 etc).
Each one of these entries has a unique value (1.06E-07, 1.80E-07, 2.91E-07 etc).
Please see the image attached.

[Data for column A, B and D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX6cc.jpg)

I have a new column D, which goes from 360-800 but in steps of 1 (360, 361, 362, 363 etc)

I want column E to have the same corresponding values as with column B, but for the new entries (361, 363, 365 etc), I want the value to be the average of the two B values it is in between.

For example, 360 should still have the value 1.06E07, but 361 should have a value of (1.06E-07 + 1.80E-07)/2. 362 should still have the value 1.80E-07. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E1 should be

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$B$7,2,FALSE),(VLOOKUP(D1-1,$A$1:$B$7,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(D1+1,$A$1:$B$7,2,FALSE))/2)`

Drag it down for the rest plus change the range, I only used a 7 row sample.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a beginners approach (I'm pretty sure, there are lots of ways to do this)

I would start by filling the values for the even numbers by vlookup. After that put it in an if function that checks for ISERROR. for the case of an error, i.e. the value can not be found (your odd numbers) add two vlookups, one for the value - 1, and one for the value + 1, then add those two up and divide them by two.

Comment: I see we went for the same approach at the same time! :)

Comment: Nice! I was just gonna type the numbers up and get a working formula myself:)

Answer (score 0):

Another formula using **AVERAGEIFS** function that can be used.

```
=IF(MOD(D1,2)=0,SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D1),AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&(D1-1),A:A,"<="&(D1+1)))
```